# Derivation of Fourier Transform in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, definition, conventions, fourier-transform

I recently came across an expression for Fourier Transform in Quantum Mechanics given by:
$$
\psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{ipx}{\hbar}} \phi(p) d p
$$

I tried to derive with starting with the Fourier Transforms, and it went like this:
$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\rho) e^{i x p} d p
$$
$$
F\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\hbar}}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(\frac{p}{\sqrt{\hbar}}\right) e^{i\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\hbar}}\right)\left(\frac{p}{\sqrt{\hbar}}\right)} d\left(\frac{p}{\sqrt{\hbar}}\right)
$$
$$
F\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\hbar}}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(\frac{p}{\sqrt{\hbar}}\right) e^{\frac{i x p}{\hbar}} d p
$$

I'm not able to find a way to get the arguments of both the function and its Fourier transform from $\frac{x}{\sqrt{\hbar}}$ to x and $\frac{p}{\sqrt{\hbar}}$ to p.

Any clue (or a complete answer) is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of pictures.

Comment: There are some basic math errors here. Also, you violate dimensionality, in particular by not distinguishing the momentum $p$ and wave vector $k$.

Comment: @RogerVadim oh, I see. Um, is there a way to derive the first expression I showed just from the basic Fourier transform?

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Okay shall make sure next time.

Comment: You might consider to change it also for *this* post.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: start with basic Fourier transform
$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int dk f(k)e^{ikx}dk
$$
and perform a change of integration variable:
$$p=\hbar k.$$

Comment: While performing this change of integration variable, f(k) changes to f(p/hbar), but in the equation above (the one I wanted to prove), it's just f(p). How do you just get f(p) from f(p/hbar)?

Comment: You define a new function $\bar{f}(p)=f(\frac{p}{\hbar})$ - the problem arises because I used the same name of the function in the definition of the Fourier transform as you want in the final result.

Comment: I see, thank you.
Another query: In the Fourier transform we started with, x is position and k happens to be the wave number. Did we take it to be the wave number 'solely' because doing so makes the power of e dimensionless? Is there any other explanation?

Comment: In principle, in mathematical Fourier transform everything is dimensionless - we can introduce dimensionality/units by dividing dimensional numbers by constants. Here the problem is that $xp$ is clearly not dimensionless.